# C Shell no difference print success message

Tags: csh

I would like to check how to print a success message if there is no difference in the two files.

Example

```
diff file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell environment `$?` gives the result of the last command.  It will be 0 if the files match, non 0 if they are different.

```
diff file1 file2
if ($? == 0) then
    echo "Same"
else
    echo "Different"
endif
```

I you are doing this, you might want to consider `diff -q` which will just return the result code and not output the differences to stdout.

Comment: thanks. what if i would like to store the result of diff to a variable?


diff file1 file2 > j

Comment: diff file1 file2 > results_file (note no -q) will work. You can still check the result with if($? == 0)

Comment: Depending on how old your csh/tcsh is you might want to use `$status` instead of `$?`

Answer (score 2):

The exit code of `diff` is zero if the files the same, one if they are different and 2 if there is an error. Use `$?` to check the exit code of the last command, or use the command directly in an `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

You might also check the length of the output with wc